# using PHP for each to get dynamic values from table

Tags: php, foreach

It's been a while since I looked at php and I've got a brain block.  I'm trying to get the values from a table using foreach so that I can store the values in a session and also display the number of items that have been ordered.

eg 2 of item number 4 etc

here's the table / form

```
        <form id="products" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <?php 
                //every item from the products table is queried because all fields need to be displayed
                $sSQL = "SELECT * FROM products";
                $rsResult = mysql_query($sSQL);
            ?>
            <table id="products_table">
                <tr style="font-weight:bold">
                    <td style="text-align:center">ID</td>
                    <td>Ref No.</td>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">Price</td>
                    <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>Add To Order</td>

               </tr>
            <!--for each record in the table that matches the query a row is created in the table and the data in the relevant field is displayed-->   
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsResult)){ ?>
                <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="productID[<? echo $row['productID']; ?>]" value="<? echo $row['productID']; ?>" />
                    <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $row['productID']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['productReference']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['productName']; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $row['productDescription']; ?></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right"><? echo '£'. $row['productPrice']; ?></td>

                    <td style="text-align:center"><span>Qty</span><input type='text' name="qty[<? echo ($_POST['qty']); ?>]" value="" ></td>
           <? } ?> 
            </table>
```

Heres the php

```
 <?php 
          foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
              echo $key . ' ' .$value.'<br />';
              print_r($key);
          }
?>
```

I know that the php is no where complete for filling sessions etc, I just can't work out how to get the values out of the form.  This php was my attempt to try and at least get some kind of value out of it

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. Where do you end the form tag? 2. what do you get if you `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your comment, the form tag was missed out when I copied and pasted the code

Answer (score 1):

in your code , there is no need of

```
 <input type="hidden" name="productID[<? echo $row['productID']; ?>
```

field .
also change the line

```
<td style="text-align:center"><span>Qty</span><input type='text' name="qty[<? echo ($_POST['qty']); ?>]" value="" ></td>
```

to

```
<td style="text-align:center"><span>Qty</span><input type='text' name="qty[<? echo ($row['productID']); ?>]" value="" ></td>
```

so that after the submission of the form , you can access the posted values with :

```
 $sSQL = "SELECT * FROM products";
 $rsResult = mysql_query($sSQL);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsResult))
 {
     echo $_POST['qty'.$row['productID']];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just display data in inputs with proper names?

Comment: you have `<td style="text-align:center"><span>Qty</span><input type='text' name="qty[<? echo ($_POST['qty']); ?>]" value="" ></td>
` I suggest you to store the values not in the name array but in the value attribute as it must be. the name will remain `name="qty[]"` and when you will submit your form you will be able to get the values from `$_POST['qty']` no matter using foreach or not. if you need multiple values you can serialize `$_POST['qty']` and pass it somewhere you need.

Comment: Ok, after playing with my code using your advice this is what I got...    <?php
   
   if(isset($_POST['order'])){
    foreach (($_POST['qty']) as $key => $value)
    echo "$value is value, $key is key<br />";
    }   
   ?>  I left the name as just "qty[]" and the value blank.  When I tried $_post['qty'] it just displayed array so at least I'm one step further than I was yesterday.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1267224 try this for example
`<?php 
if(isset($_POST)&&(!empty($_POST))){
$a=$_POST['qty'];
foreach($a as $key=>$val){
 echo "key:".$key." value:".$val."<br/>"; 
}
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="input.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="qty[]" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="qty[]" value="2"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`